# Google rejected my app because I made users go to developer option by opening settings without their permission

Tags: flutter, dart, android-manifest

Google rejected my app because I made users go to developer option by opening settings without their permission. How can I grant permission to write system settings in flutter app?

```
void openDeveloperOptionsSettings() async {
  AndroidIntent intent = const AndroidIntent(
    action: 'android.settings.APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS',
  );
```

```
bool jailbroken;
  try {
    jailbroken = await FlutterJailbreakDetection.jailbroken ||
        await FlutterJailbreakDetection.developerMode;
  } on PlatformException {
    jailbroken = true;
  }

  if (jailbroken) {
    openDeveloperOptionsSettings();
}
```

I used this code to make the app go developer option setting before opening the app and now I want how to ask permission from the user to go to the developer option system setting. Thank you.

I tried

````
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS" /> 
```in AndroidManifest.xml file but I cannot directly request the WRITE_SETTINGS permission.
````